# Is there any CLI tool to connect to MySQL server using a URL (mysql://xxx)?

Tags: mysql

I know how to use

```
mysql -u username -pPASSWD -h hostname -P port databasename
```

to connect but I need a tool that can use the RFC 1738 URL (`mysql://user:passwd@hostname:port/databasename?charset=utf8`) since I get this string as input for my script.

Is there such a tool? The mysql client doesn't seem to support the aforementioned URLs.

Comment: yes this would be very useful to test connection parameters like useTimezone=true etc.

Answer (score 4):

[`mycli`](https://www.mycli.net/) provides this.

```
mycli mysql://username:password@host:port/database?parameter=value
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the tool [Sandman](https://github.com/jeffknupp/sandman) provides this capability.

Honestly, were this my problem to solve, I'd break out sed/awk, or better yet, I'd tap the relevant developer on the shoulder & get them to change the output string to something useful.